# libevent: query parsing segmentation error

Tags: c++, parsing, segmentation-fault, libevent

I get segmentation error on trying to parse query obtained from the uri . Here is the pastebin [link](http://pastebin.com/hyM2jBwz) representing it cleanly.

Comment: pastebin it here so it does not get deleted when someone runs into same problem.

Comment: the pasted content here looks pretty ugly and tough to read